# java io exception Broken Pipe

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ioexception

I am writing an Android application in Eclipse and have had some issues between git(SourceCode) and eclipse.  After resolving one such issue which is essentially that every time i pull from git eclipse loses the libraries, this error began to occur.  It still lets me run all of the android applications without crashing but it makes debugging my applications almost impossible as it is constantly popping up this text (about every 2-3 seconds while running an app).  I do not know what other information would be helpful to provide.  I read another thread about this possibly resulting from infinite recursion but since the applications are running perfectly I don't think that it is an issue I am equipped to fix.

Below is the output from the console:

```
[2013-05-22 15:32:19 - ddmlib] Broken pipe
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:607)
at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:348)
at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:453)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:835)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:803)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:763)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:652)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:580)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error eventually went away after a combination of rebooting, remaking and repulling from github... Pretty sure this is an eclipse problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `adb kill-server` command addressed the problem for me.